# Custom Tab Bar (Second one)

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, tabbar

I am fairly new to development. Currently I have a customised tab bar (using images for each tab) that works perfectly and also includes a table view and navigation view that then leads to a second tab bar (which I want to have different tab images). When I try to implement the same code in the second tab bar area it does not work and instead of making the second tab bar change it changes the first tab bar to my new images. How can I stop this from happening by using the same code or how do I need to change the code (obviously the images change for the second tab bar). I am sure there is something simple I probably need to add or change. This is the code:

```
UIImage *selectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabImage1DB.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabImage1LB.png"];

UIImage *selectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabImage2DB.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabImage2LB.png"];

UIImage *selectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabImage3DB.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabImage3LB.png"];

UIImage *selectedImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabImage4DB.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabImage4LB.png"];

UIImage *selectedImage4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabImage5DB.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabImage5LB.png"];

UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *item2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
UITabBarItem *item3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
UITabBarItem *item4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4];

[item0 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage0 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage0];
[item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage1 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage1];
[item2 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage2 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage2];
[item3 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage3 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage3];
[item4 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage4 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage4];
```

---

This is how my current code is and it still isn't working.

```
UITabBarController *townTabViewController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
townTabViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);

// Set each tab to show an appropriate view controller
[townTabViewController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:townTabViewController, nil]];

// Add the tab controller view to the parent view
[self.view addSubview:townTabViewController.view];

UIImage *selectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HomeDB.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"HomeLB.png"];

UIImage *selectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabImage2DB.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabImage2LB.png"];

UIImage *selectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabImage3DB.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabImage3LB.png"];

UIImage *selectedImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabImage4DB.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabImage4LB.png"];

UIImage *selectedImage4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabImage5DB.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabImage5LB.png"];

UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *item2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
UITabBarItem *item3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
UITabBarItem *item4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4];

[item0 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage0 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage0];
[item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage1 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage1];
[item2 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage2 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage2];
[item3 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage3 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage3];
[item4 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage4 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage4];
```

Comment: You have two tab bars in one app?

Comment: may this https://github.com/rptwsthi/CustomUITabBar help you. you can ask for the detail if you want.

Comment: @woz yes correct, two tab bars in one app, there will be three in total by the end infact

Comment: `self.tabBarController` will refer to the first tab bar you have set up already. You need to `init` a new tab bar controller an add it to your second view.

Comment: @rptwsthi There was no project just the files.

Comment: @woz where would I implement the init? Within the implementation file above this code or in the .h?

Comment: In the code above. I'll post an answer with a rough idea...

Comment: @woz That would be perfect!! Thanks so much.

Comment: @RobertS yes and these files contains a custom tab bar wit understanding of how to use that. import these file feed the delegate (Just like table View) an you are good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code above, `self.tabBarController` is referring to the UITabBarController you have already setup. You need to create new one for this view -- something like this:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);

 // Set each tab to show an appropriate view controller
[tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fooViewController, barViewController, nil]];

// Add the tab controller view to the parent view
[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

Now you can change the tab bar by referring to it as `tabBarController.tabBar`.

Comment: Just to let you know, once i segue from one tabbar (using a table view) it then changes over to the new tab bar, which I want to customise and it won't let me.

Comment: if the tabbarcontroller is called ... townTabViewController.m How would i impliment it in this?

Comment: I can't figure out where to put this code? I get an error on the middle part of the code.

Comment: the error keeps coming up with the bit below....It says use of undeclared identifier 'fooViewController' did you mean UIViewController.                                                                       [tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fooViewController, barViewController, nil]];

Comment: `fooViewController` and `barViewController` are just bogus placholders for whatever your view controllers are that you need to put there.

Comment: which view controllers would I put there? The one which holds the previous tab bar?

Comment: Whatever view controllers you want to be displayed when the tabs are clicked -- probably not the same ones as the previous tab bar.

Comment: I figured out because it is basically a tabbar nested within another tab bar and I hide it once it crosses over to the new view controller. Is there anyway I can number the objectAtIndex? Didn't seem to work when I changed the objectAtIndex:5 and so on.....Been trying to work this out all day and still no luck!

Comment: would you be able to provide me with an example of how you would implement your code within my code above so I can copy and paste it in and change appropriate fields to my custom fields? Thanks for your help with this.